# Microsoft Word Making Half of the Formula Invisible in Text

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to write a formula in the middle of a text and strangely Microsoft Word just vanishes half of my formula. I did everything I could, but it seems to be some problem with the inline/wrap text options, but I do not know how to access them for the formula. Why is this happening?

[image: MS Word math formula]

Answer (score 1):

Applying 1.0 line spacing to the formula itself solved the problem.

Comment: And what about for people who do not want to use 1.0 line spacing?